# Populate input field based on checkbox id values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field defined like this:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" title= "language" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Insert Languages"/>
</form>
```

I wrote up a mock jQuery script just to put the word "Yes" based on whether a checkbox has been checked.  Look here:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#checkbox').change(function(){
        if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) { 
            $("input[Title='language']").val("Yes"); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

However, it's not working and there are no errors in the console.   I'm new to jQuery and am having a hard time understanding where exactly to put it, and how `$(document).ready(function () {` functions, so that may be the problem.

The non-working example can be seen here http://dreaminginswahili.com/admin/mapv4.html on the languages pane.

Comment: Why can't you just use the same code that you're using on the other tabs?

Comment: Where is your checkbox? Can you add that to your html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#checkbox')` looks for an element with `id="checkbox"`, like this

```
<input type="text" id="checkbox" />
```

but you don't have any in your html, so nothing happens.

If you have checkbox elements like `<input type="checkbox" />`, then you can select the checkboxes like this:

```
$(':checkbox')
```

and you can select the "checked" boxes like this:

```
$(':checkbox:checked')
```

Comment: This works.  Accepting in 9 minutes.  Question- how would I get the textbook to append the value of the checkbox ID with a comma for each checked checkbox?  And then remove that once the checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: This is actually the example given in the documentation! http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: You're wonderful.  You've saved me so much headache.  Thank you